# Use static javascript file on client and nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a node.js server running which has a static content folder.  I have model code which I would like both the server and the client to have, so I placed it in my static content folder.  I used `module.exports = {MyClass}` so that on the server, I can import it with `const MyClass = require('./static-content/MyClass.js');`.  This works for the server, however, the client isn't able to do a `require` and if I place the script in the html with `<script language="javascript" src="MyClass.js" > </script>`, then I get an error:

> ReferenceError: module is not defined

Is there a way for both the client and the server to use a javascript file without creating duplicates of the model code?  The context is that I have an object on the server that needs to be passed back and forth between the server and client.  As it has circular references and functions, I can't simply `JSON.stringify` the object, so I am manually taking its state, turning it into a JSON object, sending it over a WebSocket and reversing it on the client.

Comment: `<script type="module"> import { tag } from './html.js'` try this? https://www.sitepoint.com/using-es-modules/

Comment: When I do that, I still get the error `module is not defined` on the client due to the `module.exports` at the bottom of my module class, which is required to include on the server.

Comment: check if polyfill helps https://github.com/wesbos/es6-articles/blob/master/50%20-%20Polyfilling%20ES6%20for%20Older%20Browsers.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply check if `module` exists in the scope. If yes, export it else do nothing. Consider the following example:

static/Testclass.js

```
class TestClass {
    constructor(someParam = 'initial state') {
        this.someField = someParam;
    }
    doStuff() {
        return `${this.someField}`;
    }

}

const testClassInstance = new TestClass('some other state');

if (typeof (module) !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = {
        TestClass,
        testClassInstance
    };
}
```

static/test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="/static/TestClass.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <p id="test2"></p>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("test").innerText = new TestClass().doStuff();
        document.getElementById("test2").innerText = testClassInstance.doStuff();
    </script>
</body>
```

server.js

```
const TestClass = require('./static/TestClass').TestClass;
const testClassInstance = require('./static/TestClass').testClassInstance;
let  testObj = new TestClass();
console.log(testObj.doStuff());
console.log(testClassInstance.doStuff());

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use('/static', express.static('static'));
app.listen(port);
```

This would log

```
initial state
some other state
```

to the console when the server is started and the two paragraphs on the html-page would contain these contents as well.